# problem with apt upgrade when install MySQL in Ubuntu 19.4

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, mysql

i trying to install `mysql`  in `ubuntu` 19.4 but i can't upgrade with   `sudo apt upgrade`

this is the output ;

```
astrix@astrix:~/Downloads$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server-5.7
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,247 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 219928 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_amd64.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new mysql-server-5.7 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new mysql-server-5.7 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
astrix@astrix:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hossein,

the simplest thing you can run this command,

> sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat

then running upgrade once again refer to this link [askubunu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

but don't forget to backup first so you can restored it later.